# Making Android app portrait only makes it one-way portrait

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

I've made my app portrait-only and it works successfully, however there seems to be a cache. I can only have this kind of orientation:

[[image: Image]]

But I can't rotate it 180°, it just shows like this:

[image]

But if I leave the app, the screen rotates. So the problem is, it seems that the app is being set to one-way portrait, is there a way to fix it? Here's how I'm setting portrait-only in each activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Is there an option to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this instead...

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

If this doesn't work let me know!

*Edit*
So people see this, it only works with API 9+ as @AbAppletic said in the comments below.

Comment: Thank you. If you found the question useful for future visitors, please upvote it.

Comment: Added in an edit so everyone can see it easily. Thanks! :)